# How can you get the font size to persist in P4Merge on Windows?

Tags: diff, p4merge

Longtime user of P4Merge on Mac. Love it.  Now I have to do some Windows work so I grabbed it for that platform.  Problem is no matter what I do, I can't get my chosen font size to stick. It keeps resetting every time I reopen it.

I've tried:

- Changing the font when launched from SourceTree
- Changing the font while launched directly from the start menu
- Looked around (unsuccessfully) for where the preferences file would be

Anyone know how to make the font size stick? (I'd also be open to something other than P4Merge if it a) provides 3-way merging, and b) provides side-by-side diffs since I can't stand that inline view of SourceTree!)